# copy "this folder" to network drive (Robocopy or PowerShell)

Tags: powershell, robocopy

Have a folder structure on local drive like this
and a similar structure on network drive like

```
C:\Documents\Projects\ 
\\myServer\Storage\Projects\
```

For each new project I create locally folders like

```
 \Projects\abc\Subfolder1
 \Projects\abc\Subfolder2
```

I need PowerShell or Batch file. The batch is stored in folder abc and it shall perform

```
Robocopy C:\Documents\Projects\abc \\myServer\Storage\Projects\abc
```

(of course some switches are reasonable)

Next project, for example xyz

```
\Projects\abc\Subfolder1
\Projects\abc\Subfolder2
```

I expect

```
 Robocopy C:\Documents\Projects\xyz \\myServer\Storage\Projects\xyz
```

Each time I create new project I copy my sample folder structure that is supposed to contain the batch so I can quickly do copy for the project to network,

I think this can be solved by using variables for local and server base path or by doing som

Comment: And *what* is the question? Do you want the cmd shell pass the current directory to commands like robocopy, copy, xcopy, PowerShell, ... ?

Comment: Can't you use robocopy to purge and mirror? Using robocopy on the c:\Documents\Projects folder would mean just one script that could be run to check and update and new files/folders

Comment: I'm guessing you know about mirror? https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/1073.robocopy-and-a-few-examples.aspx#Mirror_a_directory_with_subfolders_incl_empty_directories

Answer (score 1):

I don't know which Robocopy parameters you need, but this could be a start. This assumes that you place this script in each \Projects\abc directory and run it from there.

```
$DestinationShare = '\\myServer\Storage'
$SourcePath = $PSScriptRoot
$DestinationPath = $PSScriptRoot -replace ".*?(?<path>\\Projects\\.*)","$DestinationShare`${path}"
robocopy $SourcePath $DestinationPath
```

This could be turned into a function that would have less static coding.

It is going to be simpler to just robocopy the entire Projects directory whenever it is required.

Answer (score 0):

In batch you could do something like this:

```batch
@echo off

set "src=%~dp0"
set "dst=\\myServer\Storage"

for /d %%d in (%src%.) do set "name=%%~nd"

robocopy %src% %dst%\%name%\ /mir
```

`%~dp0` is the directory in which the script resides. The `for` loop then extracts the name of that directory from the full path.